# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Mythology & Folklore has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Chenmunka]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: HDE 226868]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5993058513453056).

Answer (score 5):

Thank you to everyone who took the time to vote.
Thanks too to cmw for coming forward to stand.

I look forward to supporting this valuable site.

Comment: Congrats Chenmunka, and welcome to the team!

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations to Chenmunka on their victory! I know they have the expertise to moderate the site well, and I wish them all the best going forward. Thanks also, of course, to cmw for throwing their hat in the ring.

As the outgoing moderator:

It's been almost seven years since I started moderating Mythology & Folklore - long before the "& Folklore" was even a part of the name. I've had a wonderful time serving in the role, as well as broadening my mythological knowledge. For a while, though, I've had very little time to dedicate to anything on the site beyond my role as a mod, which is why I felt it was time to step down. I'm very happy with how the election process went, though, and I look forward to seeing Chenmunka step into their role as a moderator on Mythology & Folklore.

Answer (score 2):

My belated congratulations to Chenmunka as new moderator, I think you'll be a great fit and hope your moderatorship will suit you and this Stack (of which I have little doubt).

And of course a well deserved thanks to HDE 226868! You where a good and fair moderator and this Stack will never forget your contributions, and while I'm not here as much as I would like, I still hope to see you as a contributing member.

Gratias tibi ago